# How to make Image data to 2-D distribution plot?

Tags: deep-learning

How to make Image data to 2-D distribution plot ?
I want to visualize image date to 2-dimensional distribution.
Is this possible ?

Image like MNIST : [image]

2D distribution like this :[image]

Comment: what is exactly `P(x)` and `Q(x)`?

Comment: @M.DoostiLakhani That image is just show 2-d distribution. P(x) or Q(x) doesn't matter.I just want to plot MNIST data to 2D dist.

Answer (score 0):

About mnist, it does not mean anything I think. Because you have one channel of binary image so you have only zero or one. So you cannot have any plot like that.

But if you have `grayscale` image or `colored` image, you can do this:
source image:
[image: source]

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('img.jpg', -1)
cv2.imshow('image',img)

color = ('b','g','r')
for channel,col in enumerate(color):
    histr = cv2.calcHist([img],[channel],None,[256],[0,256])
    plt.plot(histr,color = col)
    plt.xlim([0,256])
plt.title('Histogram for color scale picture')
plt.show()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: 3-channel cv2]

And if your image is grayscale:

```
# 1 channel image - grayscale
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

gray_img = cv2.imread('mnist.png')
cv2.imshow('image',gray_img)
hist = cv2.calcHist([gray_img],[0],None,[256],[0,256])
plt.hist(gray_img.ravel(),256,[0,256])
plt.title('Histogram for gray scale picture')
plt.show()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: grayscale cv2]

And the `matplotlib` way is:

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img=mpimg.imread('img.jpg')
imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
plt.hist(img.ravel(), bins=256, fc='k', ec='k')
```

[image: matplotlib]